# DrupalDefaultEntityController invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: 7, database

Been trying for the last hour to work this one out.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query -> entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
       -> entityCondition('bundle', 'subscription');

$results = $query->execute();

if(isset($results['node'])) {
    $subscription_nids = array_keys($results['node']);
    $nodes = node_load_multiple($subscription_nids, TRUE);
    return $nodes;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

This is a very simple version of the entire query, but the error is exactly the same:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in DrupalDefaultEntityController->buildQuery() (line 290 of /var/www/ml/data/www/ml.mailapproved.com/includes/entity.inc).
```

I don't understand what's wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2nd argument for [`node_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7) is an array of conditions; currently you're providing a boolean so when the `buildQuery` function tries to iterate over the variable you get a warning.

The 3rd argument is to reset the cache (I guess that's what you're trying to do), so the call should be:

```
$nodes = node_load_multiple($subscription_nids, array(), TRUE);
```